# Problems with JSLint options in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: aptana, jslint

I have configured Aptana Studio 3 to use JSLint for validation. At least some of the JSLint options don't seem to work correctly, however. For example, the code below produces errors on the line f = function() { -- because of the missing space after function -- and on the line j = i++; -- because of the use of ++. Both of these errors should have been suppressed by the options. If I run this same code through the jslint.org site, I get no errors. If I reverse the options (put false in place of true) the errors go away in Aptana but now jslint.org shows errors. So it appears the options are backwards. In addition, in Aptana the absence of use strict is not flagged as an error, regardless of the "sloppy" option.

```
/*jslint white:true, plusplus:true*/
var f;
f = function() {
    var i, j;
    j = i++;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a bug report with Aptana on this issue.
http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4129